# Can I sign two softwares with single p12 certificate in Flash Builder

Tags: apache-flex, air, certificate, desktop-application

I have problems with releasing a build of a desktop application build in Flash Builder, using Flex and AIR. I have .p12 certificate which I use in another desktop application, again built in Flash Builder, using Flex and AIR. With this application, everything works fine. I am exporting release builds every week. Now I am trying to understand, why I can not export a release build of the other application with the same certificate. Can I sign both applications with the same certificate? Is there something that I have to change in the configuration files(I mean something connected to the certificate)?

The error I am getting on release: "Error creating native installer file: Unable to build a valid certificate chain for the signer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, we sign all our software with the same certificate, because the signature is to show who is the publisher. About the error I have no idea, I had soem similar erros when I had the new signiture and I had to follow some complex steps to export it as p12 using a browser but if the exact same p12 works on other app then I have no idea what it could cause that. Are you sign them with the exact same file and using same computer/IDE/environment?

Comment: Yes, I am signing both applications with the same file, on the same machine and environment. The case is that the old certificate expired. I created new one. I can not remember if I did something in addition when I started using the new certificate on the other app.

Comment: @IvanNikolov try exporting the certificate again, I had some complex instructions from the people who sold us the certificate that I had to follow, from the message it looks like something like a bad export of the certificate but I can't be sure

Comment: Guys, it is my mistake. I used wrong certificate. Sorry for taking your time for this!